# Is Windows 7 Home Edition set to shut down if mouse is unplugged?

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

The other night at the exact moment when I unplugged the mouse (USB) of my PC running Windows 7 Home Edition, the computer shut down instantly. It started back up fine and there were no problems. Is this normal? Does Windows 7 *require* a mouse?

Comment: Has it happened a second time?  Can you repeat the actions and cause the problem.  How is the battery?  Was it plugged into the mains?

Comment: It did not happen again when I pulled the mouse cable out a second time. The only thing I can think of is that the first time I pulled it out, my hand bumped the mass of wires where the power strip was and I afterwards secured it. But the second time I unplugged the cable carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not normal. Windows 7 will work without a mouse. Also you should be able to unplug USB devices on a running machine. It sounds to me like some electrical spike or short circuit occurred and the power just shut down. This would mean that either your mainboard or power supply is not working properly any more.